# Use data in .csv file as arguments for macro in TiKZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, csv, arguments

I have a .csv file with numbers I'd like to use as arguments in a TiKZ macro I've created. I've tried several different approaches but seem to be running into problems with expanding arguments (*really* don't want to try `\expandafter` again), as I can't work out how to call the data from the file without using a macro as an argument for my TiKZ macro.

**MWE:**

```
\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
10,4.2,green
20,6.4,blue
30,5.4,red
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\spoke}[3]{%true angle, radius, colour
    \fill[#3] (450-#1-5:0) -- (450-#1-5:#2) -- (450-#1-5:#2) arc (450-#1-5:450-#1+5:#2) -- (450-#1+5:0) -- (450-#1+5:#2) -- cycle;
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\spoke{10}{4.2}{green}   %how do I get these from the file?

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I'm using Overleaf, so I'm flexible about packages/approaches. I have full control over the input as well, so if there's an easier way than using a .csv I'd be very happy to use that instead.

Comment: The `csvsimple` package should do what you want. There's a simple TikZ example in the documentation.

Comment: @AlanMunn I *knew* I must have overlooked something! Thank you! Much more elegant than the nonsense I was trying :)

Comment: if you can control  the format why use csv rather than simply using `\input` a file with rows like `\spoke{10}{4.2}{green}`

Comment: The `\spoke` command involves way more coordinates than it really uses. You can shorten it to ` \fill[#3] (450-#1-5:0) -- (450-#1-5:#2) 
 arc (450-#1-5:450-#1+5:#2);`. Note, however, that this is the deprecated syntax for arcs, you really want to use `\fill[#3] (450-#1-5:0) -- (450-#1-5:#2) 
 arc[start angle=450-#1-5,end angle=450-#1+5,radius=#2];`. (You can add `- - cycle` for aesthetics but as long as you only use `\fill` you do not need it .)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Because my actual data has about 250 ```\spoke```s per picture, with different numbers and colour values. My programming knowledge is very poor at this point so the conversion wouldn't be easy for me. But thank you, I wasn't aware that was an option :)

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat That's beautiful, thank you! It reduced my compile time to about a fifth of the original. :)

Comment: It isn't clear what conversion or programming you need, no loop or programming is needed here.

Comment: You're welcome! (catcodes are usually very fast. ;-)

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat but if they are in a sealed box can you observe whether they are fast or not fast?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle The photons tunnel through the boundary of the box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `csvsimple` package can do this quite simply. :) I've also added the TikZ code suggestion made in [Schrödinger'scat's](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/19470/) comment to your question.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname-data.csv}
angle,radius,colour
10,4.2,green
20,6.4,blue
30,5.4,red
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\spoke}[3]{%true angle, radius, colour
\fill[#3] (450-#1-5:0) -- (450-#1-5:#2) 
    arc[start angle=450-#1-5,end angle=450-#1+5,radius=#2]; 
% modified and more modern code here from Schrödinger'scat in the comments
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\csvreader[head to column names]{\jobname-data.csv}{}{
\spoke{\angle}{\radius}{\colour}   %how do I get these from the file?
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]